# drawImage() refuses to draw images instantiated outside method

Tags: java, graphics

I'm currently trying to print images to the screen in order to get ready to create a game. I CAN display images by themselves, but only if the image is instantiated within the `paintComponents()` class. I, of course, don't want to re-instantiate the entire board every frame but can't seem to get it to work. How would I accomplish this?

I've tried to declare an image class-wide and instantiated it in the class' constructor. Once I tried to call `drawImage()` though, the image refused to show up. This problem went away once I instantiated it in `printComponents()`. I have tried (minorly) using a JLabel and JIcon but haven't had much luck. Especially since I can't use drawImage with a JLabel.

This is what **doesn't** work:

```
public class Skeleton extends JPanel
{

    BufferedImage img = null;

    public Skeleton()
    {
        try{
            img = ImageIO.read(new File(myFile.png));
        } catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("Loading failed.");
        }
        while(true)
        {
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public paintComponents(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawImage(img, 50, 50, null);
    }   
}
```

This **does** work:

```
public class Skeleton extends JPanel
{


    public Skeleton()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public paintComponents(Graphics g)
    {
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try{
            img = ImageIO.read(new File(myFile.png));
        } catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("Loading failed.");
        }

        g.drawImage(img, 50, 50, null);
    }   
}
```

I'd like to eventually create a double array of Tile objects that contain a preloaded image, like `myFile.png` that I could call upon to print such as `g.drawImage(tiles[1][1].getTexture(), 50, 50, null);`

Loading my files works, as I never throw an exception and the code works fine when in `paintComponents`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I would do 2 things differently: First of all I tested both versions and both did not work for me. I suppose this could be caused by the infinite loop you create in the constructor as it will never exit out of it.

Apart from that you seem to have a mistake in your paintMethod (it should actually be paint and override the super method in JPanel) you will need to make a change for the updates. I would suggest you take a look at "Game-Loops" though it could also work with a seperate Thread for every instance although I would advise against that. I corrected your code so that you can take a look at it: First version with the seperate Thread:

```
package stackoverflowtests;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Skeleton extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    private BufferedImage img = null;

    public Skeleton() {
        setSize(1000, 500);
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("index.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Loading failed.");
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(img, 50, 50, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) repaint();
    }

}
```

and for the main something like that:

```
package stackoverflowtests;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    public Main() {
        setSize(1280, 720);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Skeleton skeli = new Skeleton();
        skeli.setLocation(0, 0);
        skeli.setSize(1000, 500);
        add(skeli);
        new Thread(skeli).start();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();

    }
}
```

Possibility 2 with the game loop:

```
package stackoverflowtests;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Skeleton extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage img = null;

    public Skeleton() {
        setSize(1000, 500);
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("index.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Loading failed.");
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(img, 50, 50, null);
    }

}
```

and for the main:

```
package stackoverflowtests;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    public Main() {
        setSize(1280, 720);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Skeleton skeli = new Skeleton();
        skeli.setLocation(0, 0);
        skeli.setSize(1000, 500);
        add(skeli);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();

        // Gameloop
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int frames = 0;
        while (true) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            while (delta >= 1) {
                // updates++;
                delta--;
            }
            System.out.println("repaint");
            main.repaint();
            frames++;
        }
    }
}
```

The second thing you will need to question yourself is whether you might just use a BufferedImage object instead of a whole JPanel for each entity ;)

Comment: This worked -- thank you so much! Also, you have a fantastic point, it would be way more smart to make a BufferedImage subclass. I really appreciate your help and your time!